# Additional backspace needed to display multiline placeholder

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, custom-close-reasons, webkit

On [community custom close reason page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/flags/site-specific-close-reasons) you need to press extra backspace button to make the multiline placeholder fully visible:

> [image]

When you are clearing the text the only first line of placeholder appears on empty text area. After the second backspace button pressing the whole placeholder appears.

Maybe there are other places with multiline placeholders, but I found only this one for now.

Reproduced: iPadOS 17, Google Chrome 117.0.5938.108

No repro: Windows 11, Google Chrome 117.0.5938.92

Comment: On the face of it, it seems like a Safari issue rather than on SE's side.

Comment: @Makyen updated

Comment: s/Safari/WebKit. Per Apple policies all browsers on iOS/iPadOS have to use the same rendering engine as Safari, WebKit.